# MFC Combobox: Show scrollbar for combobox when there is x items

Tags: combobox, mfc

I have a combobox, but it only shows scrollbar when there is more than 30 items. It causes the combobox becomes too long - can't blame it, but sometimes, people think it's ugly. So Is there a way to limit the max visible items on combobox - like I have 60 items, and the combo box shows only 10 item at a time, use scrollbar to see more items.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to limit the max visible items on combobox

Layout your combobox with the resource editor, and set the cursor to where it is marked in red:

[image]

It then immediately changes layout to this:

[image]

And this is how you set the height of a combobox list.

Comment: I tried this, but it's still show 30 items, they want it shows only 10 item :(

Answer (score 0):

Use CBS_DISABLENOSCROLL to always show the scrollbar.

Define the dropdown Width smaller in you dialog resource.

Or Adjust the height as you want inside the program.

1. Intercept the CBN_DROPDOWN notification
2. Calculate the size you want.
3. Call GetComboBoxInfo to get hwndList
4. Use SetWindowPos with SWP_NOMOVE and SWP_NOZORDER to change the size